# Are there OpenCL 2.2 features, which are available in OpenCL C++, but not available in OpenCL C?

Tags: c++, c, opencl

OpenCL 2.1 and 2.2 introduced OpenCL C++ kernel language in addition to legacy OpenCL C kernel language. I have to use OpenCL in an environment, which supports C, but doesn't support C++. Are there OpenCL 2.2 features, other than C++ syntax, which are available in OpenCL C++, but not available in OpenCL C?

Do I have to use a C++ compiler (write C++ main program) in order to use OpenCL C++ kernel language? My understanding is that some OpenCL implementations included a limited C++ compiler to handle OpenCL C++ kernel language.

Comment: I don't know about added features - you would have to look at the specs for that; but it's C++ code, so unless you're going to go to some work; you're going to be using a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it, but I don't think you need a C++ compiler to use C++ Kernel Language in OpenCL 2.1/2.2, since you're just submitting source to the driver to compile (using it's built-in C++ compiler). Of course, your host program would have to be C, not C++.

Comment: How is it done? What happens when C compiler encounters `kernel` keyword followed by C++ code?

Comment: @PaulJurczak We can't mix host code and kernel code in OpenCL.

Comment: In OpenCL the host code and kernel code are separate, so you can have C host code and C++ kernel code. In SYCL they are combined; you have a single code module for host and kernel code. But you're not using that.

Comment: @Dithermaster So the first compilation pass over the source code sends some files to C compiler and the others to OpenCL compiler, right? Is there a document somewhere describing how it is done?

Answer (score 0):

To build GPU OpenCL 2.1 code, the OpenCL compiler must support C++. You must support C++ at least in the GPU side (automatically, since it's the OpenCL compiler that contains it).

Other than that, your host code can be C code.